# Using a monit http interface as a public services status page

Tags: monit

I know it is possible to create users with read-only rights to the monit page, but is it possible to create a publicly viewed status page with read-only permissions?

Comment: I really would have like this as well. Something like uptime monitor: https://status.uptimerobot.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afraid you can't:

> If the Monit command line interface is being used, *at least one
>   cleartext password is necessary* (see bellow), otherwise the Monit
>   command line interface will not be able to connect to the Monit web
>   interface.

https://www.mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#Authentication

Regards